# React-Native: [Ubuntu] Getting error Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling enable) error

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

I have added some changes to the js file. And I am getting this error.

[[image: Here is the screenshot of the error]]

How to fix this?

Comment: Hi @user3441114! When you get a chance, please edit the question, remove the screen shot of the error and copy/paste the text of the error

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312103/react-native-module-hmrclinet-is-not-a-registered-callable-modulecalling-enable/47107809#47107809)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `adb` path was not set in the `PATH` variable. So I was getting the same error. So set path of **sdk/platform-tools** in your PATH environment variable.