# React-Native Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling enable)

Tags: android, react-native

I have set my IP and made sure it's right but when I execute`react-native run-android`

[image]

Comment: In my case, adb path was not set in the PATH variable. So I was getting the same error. So set path of sdk/platform-tools in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 15):

i had the same problem , didn't knew what to do.

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

after that

```
react-native run-android
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 8):

I resolved issue by:

1: Uninstalling app

2: Restart package: `react-native run-android`

Comment: I tried above all but nothing worked but this one worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when you have hot reloading enabled but you are in production mode. To use hot reloading, make sure you have `__DEV__` set to true.

To check or change this, in a console type `adb shell input keyevent 82`, go to Dev Settings, and make sure JS Dev Mode is checked.

If you have remote JS debugging enabled, then you might also see a line in the console that looks like this:

> `Running application "yourapp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON`

If that's the case, then this could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I accidentally unchecked Dev Mode in settings.

Answer (score 2):

you need to stop `npm` server. then hit following command in terminal.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

than start `npm server`

Answer (score 2):

same error occurs to me when I switch off JS DEV Mode and enable Hot Reloading.I solved it by disable Hot Reloading.Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Santosh's answer is correct, but I couldn't use it, so for others who run into this problem and are as much of a newbie as I am at the moment... The `adb` that Santosh is restarting here is the [Android Debugging Bridge](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/).  It seems to be at the heart of the Hot Reloading / remote debugging that's built into React Native.  Basically, it got confused and needed resetting.

***Alternate Solution***
Trying to run `adb` failed for me, so I stopped the emulator, opened the Android Virtual Device manager (in Android Studio until Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager, and on the line for the particular phone I was emulating, I clicked the down arrow next to the edit (pencil) icon to the right and selected 'Wipe Data'.  Then I restarted that device (the Play button just to the left of the edit (pencil) icon.  Restarted my app via `react-native run-ios` and everything was fine.

***More on Santosh's Solution***
To do it Santosh's way, you need the Android SDK bin folder in your path, or to run the command with full path.  It's in your Android SDK folder under `platform-tools`.  Don't forget to re-enable Hot Reloading after restarting (if you're using it).

Answer (score 1):

This issue come due to development server error.

Follow some steps to resolve this issue.

**Step 1:**

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

then check your device/emulator is visible on command prompt or not.

```
adb devices
```

**Step 2**

Clean your gradle compiler files, some file may be corrupt.

```
android/gradlew clean
```

**Step 3:**

Remove application from your device/emulator.

**Step 4:**

```
react-native run-android
```

Now issue will be resoled :)

Comment: These steps are telling us everything about the state of JavaScript Development in 2018. I want to add that you sometimes have to perform the usual node routine of `rm rf node_modules && npm install`.

Comment: With this if it still doesnot work, then just manually uninstall the app from the emulator or actual device and again try running "react-native run-android" - this way it solved mine

Answer (score 0):

if you using RN Debugger you must turn off firewall and try again, it's worked for me