# Module hmrclient is not registered react native, why is this happening and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So I have rage shaken my tablet and in dev settings, I have my JS dev mode to true yet, live/hot reloading does not work. Funny thing is, when I run the app on a colleague's Mac (the same model and everything) - it works fine.

I don't know what or why this is happening.

I've tried:

cd android && ./gradlew clean
then cd .. && react-native run-android

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/916

and also:

rm -rf node_modules && npm install
cd android && ./gradlew clean

[React-Native Module HMRClinet is not a registered callable module(calling enable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312103/react-native-module-hmrclinet-is-not-a-registered-callable-modulecalling-enable)

import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
react-native run-android

[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

None of the above solutions work.

Do you guys know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue come due to development server error.

Follow some steps to resolve this issue.

Step 1:

adb kill-server
adb start-server
then check your device/emulator is visible on command prompt or not.

adb devices
Step 2

Clean your gradle compiler files, some file may be corrupt.

android/gradlew clean
Step 3:

Remove application from your device/emulator.

Step 4:

react-native run-android
Now issue will be resoled :)

[React-Native Module HMRClinet is not a registered callable module(calling enable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312103/react-native-module-hmrclinet-is-not-a-registered-callable-modulecalling-enable)